# Get account name of specific user using their display name

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, rest, user-profile-property, person

I am targeting a Person/Group field within my page layout via JavaScript.  This enables me to get the display name for that particular user "Lastname, Firstname".

Using '.innerHTML', I can also retrieve the email address for that user.  I am wondering if I can use the "Lastname, Firstname" to lookup that particular user's account name for use elsewhere.

I have already found examples of where I can lookup various user profile properties given that my input is the account name.  However I don't have this available to me and this is the property I need to retrieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SPServices for this.  You can pass the lastname / first name and get the user object using which you can fetch user properties. See: http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SearchPrincipals

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using the code in the link you provided (SP Services - Search Principals).  Worked with some change.